# Linux: How to Press Sysreq Key in VNC/Vsphere Client?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vnc, vsphere-client

I'm using a Vsphere client on Windows XP over a VNC link (Vinagre) from an Ubuntu 10.10 desktop running WindowMaker. It all works pretty well, but I can't find *any* way to press the Magic SysReq key (used to reset Linux hard). Neither Vinagre nor Vsphere has any sort of keyboard that can be pressed; trying to use the SysReq key just results in the local system being reset. Running Vinagre in full screen makes no difference.

How do I press SysReq in this combination of software? I thought that sending a BRK would help, but there's no way to do that either. I thought PrScr would do it, but don't know how. Switching from Vinagre to xtightvncviewer didn't help at all.

Am I missing something or is sending a SysReq just not possible?

**UPDATE**: I found [information](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30768/linux-proc-sys-kernel-where-are-the-files-sysrq-sticky-sysrq-key-and-sysrq-t/30793#30793) about `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq-key` (which allows you to specify the key) but that seems to have been removed sometime during the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.x kernel lifetime. This was a feature in the mainline kernel at one time.

Comment: this could maybe help you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105295/what-numeric-key-codes-do-i-need-to-send-for-the-magic-sysrq-functionality-in-a/115773#115773

Answer (score 2):

sysrq on ESXi VNC/Console for a redhat/fedora/debian guest:

```
[ctrl+alt] (keep them pressed all the time) + [space] + <release [space]> + [PrintScrn] + <sysrq> + <release [ctrl+alt]>
```

you might also want to try [break] instead of [printscrn]

Comment: This looks like the best option for the Console itself, but with VNC not sure this could work... but will try next time I get a chance.

Comment: What if I want to press `Alt + SysReq`, is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps in your situation (won't help if the kernel is in panic) but there is a file `/proc/sysrq-trigger`:

> Using the echo command to write to this file, a remote root user can
>   execute most System Request Key commands remotely as if at the local
>   terminal.
>   [quote](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-sysrq-trigger.html)

A list of letters to `echo` to this file can be found for example [here](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sysrq.txt)

Comment: The problem I've been seeing is an apparent lockup: so this won't help - at least not from a local shell. I'm leery of making such a capability available via the network without security precautions.